# Problem verifying a contract on Etherscan

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp, decentralization

[image: what constructors missing in this]

I wrote an Ethereum contract according to official example.
When verifying it, on etherscan.io, I'm getting an error "missing constructors arguments".

What wrong and how can I correct the issue?

Here's the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract owned { address public owner;

function owned() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
    owner = newOwner;
}
}

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract TokenERC20 { // Public variables of the token string public name; string public symbol; uint8 public decimals = 18; // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it uint256 public totalSupply;
// This creates an array with all balances
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

// This notifies clients about the amount burnt
event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

/**
 * Constrctor function
 *
 * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
 */
function TokenERC20(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    string tokenSymbol
) public {
    totalSupply = 210000000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = 210000000000;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
    name = "ACCoin";                                 // Set the name for display purposes
    symbol = "AC";                            // Set the symbol for display purposes
}

/**
 * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
 */
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require(_to != 0x0);
    // Check if the sender has enough
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    // Check for overflows
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
    // Save this for an assertion in the future
    uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
    // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    // Add the same to the recipient
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
    assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
 *
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens from other address
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
 *
 * @param _from The address of the sender
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value = _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
    totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
    Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens from other account
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
 *
 * @param _from the address of the sender
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
    require(_value  bool) public frozenAccount;

/* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

/* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
function MyAdvancedToken(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    string tokenSymbol
) TokenERC20(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public {}

/* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    require (_to != 0x0);                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);               // Check if the sender has enough
    require (balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
    require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                     // Check if sender is frozen
    require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                       // Check if recipient is frozen
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
}

/// @notice Create `mintedAmount` tokens and send it to `target`
/// @param target Address to receive the tokens
/// @param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
    balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
    totalSupply += mintedAmount;
    Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
    Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
}

/// @notice `freeze? Prevent | Allow` `target` from sending & receiving tokens
/// @param target Address to be frozen
/// @param freeze either to freeze it or not
function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
    frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
    FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
}

/// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
/// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
/// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
    sellPrice = newSellPrice;
    buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
}

/// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
function buy() payable public {
    uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;               // calculates the amount
    _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);              // makes the transfers
}

/// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
/// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
function sell(uint256 amount) public {
    require(this.balance >= amount * sellPrice);      // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
    _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);              // makes the transfers
    msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);          // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
}
}
```

Comment: what parameters did you pass to the contract when you created/deployed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor function `TokenERC20()` is getting 3 input parameters on contract declaration, but you are not using any of them, because you are assigning these values directly in function.

---

Try to change your constructor function:

```
function TokenERC20() {
        totalSupply = 210000000000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = 210000000000;
        name = "ACCoin";                                 
        symbol = "AC";                            
}
```

Comment: you are really great .thanks you so much .I will follow you.

Comment: @kyawswar glad to hear it. I know you are new to StackExchange sites, you might find useful this article: [What should I do when someone answers my question.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)